# Why do I get "node: bad option" error when I pass a custom flag to nodejs command line, in a Angular 9 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, proxy-server

I am trying to add a custom flag in the npm start command, in an Angular 9 project, so that inside the local proxy server, I can intercept the proxy request and manipulate data.  But I keep getting the "node: bad option" error. Cannot figure out why. Please help me. Below is my npm start command

```
"start" : "node -max_old_space_size=8192 --enable-mock ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.js --host=0.0.0.0 --live-reload false";
```

then I just run npm start, then the `"node: bad option: --enable-mock"` error shows up in the console, I cannot even start the development server.

Answer (score -1):

When passing args to a program, Node is strict:

```
No args: node [NODE_OPTIONS] [FILE]
Args:    node [NODE_OPTIONS] <FILE> [PROGRAM_OPTIONS]
```

See? When passing args, you need to include a file (use `.` in this case for the project index.js.)